# Connecting to ldap using GSSAPI. Wrong service principal

Tags: java, ldap, kerberos, jaas, gssapi

I'm trying to connect to ldap server using SASL. I'm connecting using url `ldaps://ldap.example.com` but server hostname is `host.example.com`. `ldap.example.com` is cname for `host.example.com`. My program is trying to get service ticket for `ldap/ldap.example.com` instead of performing reverse dns request and getting ticket for `ldap/host.example.com`. Everything works fine when I'm using `ldap://host.example.com` but I prefer to use service CNAME.

There is my code for creating connection factory:

```
public DefaultConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    return new DefaultConnectionFactory(connectionConfig());
}

private ConnectionConfig connectionConfig(){
    final SaslConfig saslConfig = new SaslConfig();
    saslConfig.setMechanism(Mechanism.GSSAPI);

    final BindConnectionInitializer connectionInitializer = new BindConnectionInitializer();
    connectionInitializer.setBindSaslConfig(saslConfig);

    ConnectionConfig connConfig = new ConnectionConfig("ldaps://ldap.example.com");
    connConfig.setConnectionInitializer(connectionInitializer);
    return connConfig;
}
```

and jaas.config:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    keyTab="/etc/ldap.keytab"
    principal="ldap@EXAMPLE.COM"
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    debug=true
    ;
};
```

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should request a new certificate with `ldap.example.com` as the subject name and with `host.example.com` as a subject alternative name.  The certificate negotiation is handled right before Kerberos.

A couple more suggestions:

1. All SPNs should be defined in your KDC:

> LDAP/ldap.example.com
>
> LDAP/host.example.com

2. Both of these A records should be set in DNS.  [Avoid use of CNAMES, while it might be OK at any given time, different browser versions and future updates could cause inconsistent behavior](http://blog.michelbarneveld.nl/michel/archive/2009/11/14/the-reason-why-kb911149-and-kb908209-are-not-the-soluton.aspx):

> ldap.example.com
>
> host.example.com

3. The principal in [jaas.config](http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part1.html) and the keytab *should* match.  You have:

`principal="ldap@EXAMPLE.COM"`

I suggest it should be: `principal=“ldap/host.example.com“;`

4. Finally, ldap/host.example.com should be defined as the SPN in your keytab.  If it is not, it might be OK, as long as you either (1) add it as an additional SPN related in the keytab: [How do you add multiple SPNs to the same keytab file for Spnego or Kerberos Configuration?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/270616/how-do-you-add-multiple-spns-to-the-same-keytab-fi.html) or (2) see [Setspn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241(v=ws.11).aspx) if you are using Active Directory and you application server supports it.

See further reading on [GSSAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm not sure if you understood me correctly.
`ldap.example.com` is cname for `host.example.com` (according to your answer i shouldn't and i think that is the case) and `ldap@EXAMPLE.COM` is my client principal that have permissions in ldap. What more everything works fine i'm using `ldap://host.example.com` but I have only ldap.example.com set in my tls certificate.

Comment: I updated my answer with a statement about the certificate angle to this, as I see you made a couple edits to your question.  That should resolve this.  I would take into consideration the rest of my post regarding SPNs as a "Best Practice".